# I need to insert a vlookup in a cell after the last row that could vary from week to week

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub vlookup
    Dim TR As Long
    TR = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("F46").Formula ="=Vlookup(C46,OpenDCSInvoices!$A:$C, 3, False)"
    Range("F46").Copy
    Range("F46:F" & TR).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End sub
```

As this is a weekly report it varies so the vlookup may be inserted in a different cell depending on how big or small the data file is. This code works for this week but it won’t work for next week as it will change. I need to insert the vlookup in column F after the last cell of data as I am adding to existing data and it needs to lookup the value in column C that is adjacent to where the vlookup will start. Thank you and anything helps as I am stuck.

Comment: Do you mean the 46 will change? Given that you seemingly know to find the last row in a column, I'm not clear why you need help?

Comment: The 46 will change, yes. I don’t know how to make that a variable as well as F46 in range needs to be a variable as that will change every week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, not 100% sure I have understood. You can change the variable name to something better.

```
Sub vlookup()
    Dim TR As Long, TRf As Long
    TR = Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    TRf = Range("F" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range("F" & TRf & ":F" & TR).Formula = "=Vlookup(C" & TRf & ",OpenDCSInvoices!$A:$C, 3, False)"
End Sub
```

Comment: This works tremendously! Thank you for the help and sorry if I didn’t explain it very well.